# Logic Apps: selecting the first element of an array

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Lets say you have an array and you want to take the first element of it. can you do this via expressions. In the below example im printing it in a teams chat.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, use the `first()` expression ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#first

Simply pass in your array and it will work ...

```
first(variables('Tactic'))
```

... or, use the more programmatic approach ...

```
variables('Tactic')[0]
```

... noting that array indexes start from 0.

**Tip:** Press the `See more` button next to the `Collection` node in the `Expression` window as you've shown.